How to set font/ui size without changing resolution and refresh rate
I just got the philips envia 27M1C5500VL and installed it correctly for my desktop.
However when I wish to use the macbook with it, I notice that all text is abysmally small. This is due to the high resolution (2560 x 1440), compared to the macbook. Reading different options on the internet I could find all solutions to set "scaled", a setting that seems absent on my macbook.
I've tried to lower the resolution to 1920x1080 HiDi, which works. However now the refresh rate is only 50Hz, which actually gives me a headache when working through a full workday.
Is there a solution? Why can't I just set the text scaling for that display, or use the normal 144 Hz refresh rate?

